# What are Cassandra storage exceptions

Tags: cassandra

recently we start having Cassandra (3.10) some timeout during read / write to Cassandra.
from our monitoring, we notice that during those timeouts there is a spike at Cassandra storage exceptions metric.
I've tried to search on those exceptions and failed to find any info,
could someone explain what it means, what are the cause for it?

Comment: what are the exceptions that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Storage exceptions are generated by any unhandled exceptions, including, but not limited to, file system errors and corrupt SSTable exceptions. Check the database log for ERROR entries beginning with the words "Exception in thread" for additional details.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the source code of the exception https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/test/unit/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/IndexSummaryRedistributionTest.java#L38
We are running Cassandra reaper to make sure there no corruption of SSTABLES http://cassandra-reaper.io/